# A cyclic group of order 25 doesn't have an automorphism of order 3.

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, automorphism-group

> Let $G$ a cyclic group of order 25. Prove $\forall \phi \in{\rm Aut}(G):|\phi| \neq 3$.

I am a bit stuck and I'm not sure I'm even going in the right path.

Assume with contradiction $\exists \phi \in G$ s.t $|\phi| = 3$. This implies $\forall g \in G$ we have $\phi^3(g) = g$.

From datum $G$ is cyclic consider $g \in G$ s.t $G=<
\langle g\rangle$. This implies $\phi(g) = g^\alpha$ for some $\alpha$.

Now we have

$$\begin{align}
e_G &= \phi^3(g) \\
&=\phi^2(g^\alpha) \\
&=\phi(\phi(g) ... \phi(g)) \\
&= \phi(g^\alpha ... g^\alpha) \\
&= \phi(g^{\alpha^2})\\
& = g^{\alpha^3},
\end{align}$$

which implies $g = g^{\alpha^3}$.

Now since $G=\langle g\rangle \implies |g| = 25$ **and this is where I'm hoping to find contradiction** without success.

Comment: the identity element of $Aut(G)$ is the identity map (not map s.t. $g\to e_G\;\;\forall g\in G$). Hence in your proof, $\phi^3(g)=g$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The automorphism group of a group $G$ has function composition as operation and the identity element is the identity function.

The composition of two automorphisms is again an automorphism, so $\phi^3$ cannot send every element to $e_G$, because this map is not bijective.

So your contradiction assumption should be $\phi^3(x)=x$ for every $x\in G$, with $\phi$ not the identity map. In particular, $\phi^3(g)=g$ where $g$ is a generator of the cyclic group.

Now you know that $\phi(g)=g^a$ for some $a$ with $0<a<25$, so
$$
\phi^3(g)=g^{a^3}
$$
and therefore $g^{a^3-1}=e_G$. Thus $a^3-1\equiv0\pmod{25}$. This is impossible (prove it).

It's simpler if you consider $G=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and note that the endomorphisms of $G$ have the form $x\mapsto kx$, where $k$ is any integer in the range $0..24$. For what $k$ is this map bijective? Exactly when $kx\equiv1\pmod{25}$ for some $x$, which is the same as saying that $k$ is coprime to $25$. There are $20$ such elements, so the automorphism group has order $20$.

Comment: perfect this is exactly what I was trying to do and got confused. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach, too:

Remark that $\mathrm{Aut}(C_{n})\cong U(n)$. Hence $\mathrm{Aut}(C_{25})\cong U(25)$, and we know that $|U(25)|=20$, now by Lagrange theorem we get that there doesn't exist any element of order $3$ in $\mathrm{Aut}(C_{25})$.

As an exercise, you can prove that $U(25)\cong C_{20}$. ($U(n)$ is the group of generators of $C_{n}$.)